# Subscription to a UIButton.rx.tap located in UITableViewCell within UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, uibutton, rx-swift, reactivex, rxdatasources

Let's say I have a `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell`.
After dequeuing the cell from the `UITableView` I want to subscribe to the `UIButton.rx.tap`. The issue is that if my `UITableViewCell` is dequeued multiple times, the subscriptions would retain. Currently I solve this problem by allocating a `Disposable` property in my `UITableViewCell`, setting it when the subscription is create,  and calling `Disposable.dispose()` on `UITableViewCell.prepareForReuse()`, however as far as I understand implementing features in a way that requires you to call `Disposable.dispose()` implies that you are doing something wrong.

Is there any better way to accomplish uniqueness of the subscription without reallocating `UIButton`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another solution (which doesn't require an additional library or calling `Disposable.dispose()`) is to have a `DisposeBag` in the cell and re-create it in `prepareForReuse`, as suggested in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/437):

```
//in the cell 

private(set) var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func prepareForReuse() {
   super.prepareForReuse()
   disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}


//in the data source
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DiaryItemCell

cell.commentButton.rx_tap
            .subscribeNext{

            }.addDisposableTo(cell.disposeBag)

return cell
```

It will also work if you have more buttons (or other Observables which you want to subscribe to) in your cell. You won't have to create a new `Disposable` in the cell itself for each of them.

Comment: I came to realize your solution is actually much more elegant. What should be nice though is to develop a `DisposeBase` that can be disposed without reinstantiating it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :) Saved me from extra libraries and hacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cell-Rx](https://github.com/ivanbruel/Cell-Rx) pod form correct using reactive subscriptions in `UITableViewCell`. For your case you can use `rx_reusableDisposeBag`, it will dispose your subscriptions correct.

Comment: I forgot to call super.prepareForReuse() in my `UITableViewCell`. That's why the `rx_reusableDisposeBag` wan't resetting.

Thanks for the suggestion!