# UITableViewCell containing a UICollectionView using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I started using `RxSwift` in my iOS project and I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. Within that subclass, I have a `UICollectionView`.

Populating the `tableview` using `RxSwift` works pretty flawlessly, I'm using another extension of `RxSwift` for that ([RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources))

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
    self.dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<Section>(configureCell: {(section, tableView, indexPath, data)  in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellWithCollectionView

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.collectionViewCellNibName = "ContactDataItemCollectionViewCell"
            cell.collectionViewCellReuseIdentifier = "contactDataItemCellIdentifier"
        case 1, 2:
            cell.collectionViewCellNibName = "DebtCollectionViewCell"
            cell.collectionViewCellReuseIdentifier = "debtCellIdentifier"
        default:
            break
        }
        cell.registerNibs(indexPath.section, nativePaging: false, layoutDirection: indexPath.section != 0 ? .horizontal : .vertical)

        let cellCollectionView = cell.collectionView!

        data.debts.asObservable().bind(to: cellCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "debtCellIdentifier", cellType: DebtCollectionViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
            cell.setup(debt: data)
        }


        return cell

    })
```

This actually works. But the problem arises when a `tableview` cell gets scrolled off the screen and reappears. This triggers the code block from above and lets the app crash when

```
    data.debts.asObservable().bind(to: cellCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "debtCellIdentifier", cellType: DebtCollectionViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
        cell.setup(debt: data)
    }
```

is invoked twice on the same tableview cell (The funny thing is, even Xcode crashes without any trace).

What can I do to avoid this?

EDIT:

I have found a solution, but I must admit that I'm not really happy with it... Here's the idea (tested and works)

I define another `Dictionary` in my class:

```
var boundIndizes = [Int: Bool]()
```

and then I make an `if` around the binding like this:

```
if let bound = self.boundIndizes[indexPath.section], bound == true {
    //Do nothing, content is already bound
} else {
    data.debts.asObservable().bind(to: cellCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "debtCellIdentifier", cellType: DebtCollectionViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
        cell.setup(debt: data)
        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    self.boundIndizes[indexPath.section] = true
}
```

But I cannot believe there is no "cleaner" solution

Comment: In your fixed code you're storing the `diposable` on the `disposeBag`, but not in your first code. Are you storing it anywhere at all?

Comment: @AndreCarvalho yes I tried it with and without the `disposeBag` and it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are binding your `data.debts` to the collectionView within the cell every time the cell is dequeued.

I would recommend you move the logic that is related to your `data.debts` to the cell itself and declare a `var disposeBag: DisposeBag` which you reinstantiate on `prepareForReuse`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099315/6407425) for reference.

Comment: You are absolutely right and this just makes sense... thank you very much